# NSString to NSDate conversion error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I wrote following code to convert NSString to NSDate.

```
 [NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"NSDate is %@", _pickUpDao.pickupDate);

    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:_pickUpDao.pickupDate];



2014-05-19 14:07:45.095 ProjectName[3992:70b] NSDate is 5/20/2014
```

But I am getting following error

```
-[__NSCFCalendar components:fromDate:]: date cannot be nil
```

I mean really, what do you think that operation is supposed to mean with a nil date?
An exception has been avoided for now. A few of these errors are going to be reported with this complaint, then further violations will simply silently do whatever random thing results from the nil.

Comment: 2014-05-19 14:07:45.095 ProjectName[3992:70b] NSDate is 5/20/2014

Comment: Have you debugged your code? My guess is that _pickUpDao.pickupDate is nil and you can't do dateFromString with nil value.

Comment: You are getting correct NSLog. Your error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: What about debugging this? Like, setting an exception on breakpoints in Xcode, so you can figure out where the problem actually happens, instead of making wild guesses? There is no call to NSCalendar components:fromDate: in sight here, but that's where the problem is.

Comment: 5/20/2014 this date is invalid for your format dd/MM/yyyy, where MM here is 20. Use a valid date to check.

Comment: so what is valid format, can you tell?

Comment: To match your format string will be 20/5/2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the code takes 20 in the place of the month. ***"20"*** cannot be a month. Try changing your date format to `@"MM/dd/yyyy"`.

```
[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSLog(@"NSDate is %@", _pickUpDao.pickupDate);

date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:_pickUpDao.pickupDate];
```